# Using multiple redirect url's for an "Application registration portal" app

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, identityserver3

If I create an app in the "[Application registration portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/)", only the first redirect url works.

For example; if I add https://google.com/ first, this url works. But if I add https://localhost/ it does not.
When I add https://localhost/ first and https://google.com/ second, only the localhost url works.

The only way to make everything work is to create two separate applications in the "Application registration portal". One for the development environment and one for production.

To me it feels like some server-side cache issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it! I forgot to try the solution I found on github, which solved my problem.

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/1458

**UPDATE**

The ConfigureAuth method in my Startup.Auth.cs now contains the following code:

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = clientId,
        Authority = Authority,

        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
        {
            // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
            AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
            {
                var code = context.Code;
                ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(code, new Uri(redirectUri), credential, graphResourceId);

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            },

            RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
            {
                context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = redirectUri;
                context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri;

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        },
    }
);
```

*Note: This code is used in a ASP.NET MVC application which uses cookie based authentication.*